Terraform + AWS: reference an existing resource (usage plan) but its attributes are overriden
I am using Terraform to try bootstrap API on AWS Gateway. My goal is to create new API, but reuse some existing configs, like existing usage plans and the associated API keys. I have the following .tf:
# resources for aws_api_gateway, aws_api_gateway_deployment
...
import {
  to = aws_api_gateway_usage_plan.bulk_load
  id = "xifkaf"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "bulk_load" {
  name = "bulk_load"

  api_stages {
    api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_rest_api.id
    stage  = aws_api_gateway_stage.qa.stage_name
  }
  
}

After apply the code on AWS, I realize the existing APIs associated with this "bulk_load" usage plan is gone, and the settings for throttle rate and quota are missing too. See the attached image to demonstrate the difference.
[
I guess it's because I didn't declare the existing attributes for this usage plan. But what annoys me are:

aws_api_gateway_usage_plan on tf aws document is resource only, there is no data source for it. I am not sure if there is an entrance for it as data source can avoid this overriding.

To avoid the settings to be overrides, it seems I need to fetch the existing settings every time, and then append/update a new API entry into the usage plan. I hope there is a smarter way to avoid such error-prone manual work.


Target:
I can reference existing usage plans on AWS API Gateway to my newly created API, and also keep the settings of these usage plans unchanged, except adding one more associated API.

Is there a question here?

The usage plan I wanna attach has associated stages and attributes for rate, burst and quota. The way I implemented as above, these things are gone, as I should also state existing config for this usage plan in .tf, plus my change. But I am looking for a way, no need to manual copy-paste the config of resources in AWS, and I can update the resource in-place.
